# anchor child in anchor parent element bug

Tags: html, browser, html-rendering

Did I find the most ridiculous html rendering bug?
If you place an anchor element into another anchor element it will render the child outside it's parent: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wk9d0yd8/)

```
 <a id="parent" href="#"> 
     <a class="child" href="#">Child</a>
 </a>
```

If you change the element to a span, it works fine. [Same example with span.](https://jsfiddle.net/wk9d0yd8/1/)

```
<span id="parent"> 
     <span class="child" href="#">Child</span>
</span>
```

Since this is the same in chrome, firefox, IE, safari, on linux, mac, windows, android I tend to think that there is a hidden rule for anchor elements that I am missing.

Comment: Nested anchor tags are illegal in HTML, nested spans are not.

Comment: Ah ok, that makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since nested anchor elements are [invalid HTML](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/links.html#h-12.2.2), most browsers will try and be helpful and correct that automatically for you, resulting in:

```
<a id="parent" href="#"></a><a class="child" href="#">Child</a>
```

The reason the same thing doesn't happen with span elements is because they can be nested and the browser will not interfere.